# change images smoothly by pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do change background images smoothly without using JQuery because I don't know anything about jQuery and also I wanna learn it by using javascript.
So, I have done only that image changes in 1 second by javascript but I don't understand what can I do so images change smoothly like fading in, sliding, etc. 
So this is my code

```js
        var index = 0,
          container = document.getElementById("Imagebackground");

        function autochange() {
          var image = ['http://placekitten.com/1000/600', 'http://placekitten.com/1024/620', 'http://placekitten.com/960/600'];
          container.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image[index++] + ')';
          if (index > 2) {
            index = 0;
          }
        }
        window.setInterval(autochange, 1000);
```

```css
#Imagebackground {
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/1000/590");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="Imagebackground"></div>
```

Comment: Can I know the reason why you down-vote this question?

Comment: @Dai, Thanks for taking interest But I don't want to learn jQuery Ok. I wanna do it by using css and javascript only. But I can't figure it out how can I achieve this by javascript.

Comment: @Sunny sorry, I misread your posting.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Comment: @Zze, nice link, but in this link jQuery is used not javascript. :(

Comment: It uses CSS animation and HTML only. Zero JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS transitions. No javascript required.

If you need further explanation on this code, it can be found here under Demo 3: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

```css
@-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

#example {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#example img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}

#example img {
  -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;

  -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-duration: 8s;

  -o-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-duration: 8s;

  animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
}
#example img:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
#example img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
#example img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
#example img:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  animation-delay: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <img class="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080" />
  <img class="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/808080" />
  <img class="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FFFF/808080" />
  <img class="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF00FF/808080" />
</div>
```

Comment: Transitions are sufficient in this case, and have better browser support

Comment: Your intro text suggests to use animations, yet your code uses transitions, not animations. Also, as OP's code shows, he wants to transition more than just two images based on a timer.

Comment: @connexo Wrong word - fixed :) ... I'll make a transition loop - just for you.

Answer (score 4):

Try out this, this is pure javascript code

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 3000); 
}
```

```html
<div class="bannar">
    <img class="slides" src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Windows%20Logo.jpg" />
    <img class="slides" src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Turtle.jpg" />
    <img class="slides" src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg" />
</div>
```

And this is where you put all your images that you want to slide.

```
<div class="bannar">
    <img class="slides" src="images/bannar1.jpg">
    <img class="slides" src="images/bannar2.jpg">
    <img class="slides" src="images/bannar3.jpg">
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add (.style.transition = "..s") with JavaScript inside the function, it works fine with me

Comment: Add code sample that relate to question and combine with your answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32332085)